# Deploying my trained LSTM on SageMaker studio Serverless-Inference

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

As the title suggests, I have trained an LSTM with python using Tensorflow and Keras to predict prices, and serialized it in an .h5 file, I have been trying to find a tutorial on how I can deploy my model for my user case which is Serverless-inference since I'm not expecting a much usage of the model, it will be periodic (one a month) but to no avail.

I found some tutorial but they use XGBoost and not really that straight forward unfortunately. Can anyone direct me to a tutorial on how to or have any high view on how to do this? Thank you in advance!! let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question? Also reference to the tutorial you are referencing.